# What is this houseplant with variegated leaves that thrives growing in water?

Tags: identification, houseplants

A friend who was moving away left it with me; he had no idea what it is.  It's currently growing in a glass mason jar of water - and has grown to an impressive size doing so - and I'm trying to figure out if I should just leave it in the jar or give it some dirt in a new pot.

*Click on photo for full size*

[image: A houseplant]

Answer (score 3):

This is a variegated coleus. The nomenclature people have been busy again and this plant now seems to be in with either

> [the genus Solenostemon or in another genus, Plectranthus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleus)

.  There are [many cultivars](http://www.flickr.com/photos/thoog/6184249366/) with a wide variety of leaf shape and colour.  They are very easy to grow.  You could take your plant and put each stem in water and it would root.

This plant is a tender perennial when grown outdoors.  It requires some shade in subtropical climates or full sun and some pruning management in areas where there is a winter but the temperatures do not get below around ten degrees Celsius.

You can re pot it in any potting soil with a lot of organic matter and keep it moist.  You may choose to pinch off the flowers which are not the main attraction to keep it more compact.

Normally on these plants have more colourful leaves but under low light conditions they loose the red and yellow.  Consider putting your plant in higher light levels for a better show.